# UWP capability equivalent to Xamarin Forms MessagingCenter?

Tags: uwp

Silly question:  Is there a capability in UWP apps similar to Xamarin Forms' MessagingCenter for inTRA-process communication (pub/sub)?

MessagingCenter enables nicely decoupled communication between Views and their ViewModels or between different objects in a listview, etc. Surely there's a similar capability in a straight (non-Xamarin) UWP app, no?

Comment: You can target UWP with Xamarin Forms, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [MVVMLight](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight) in your UWP project. It has a [Messenger](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/Messaging/Messenger.cs) class. It allows exchange messages between objects.

You could use `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger.Default.Send<TMessage>(TMessage message)` method to send message and subscribe/register the message receiver by calling `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger.Default.Register<TMessage>()` method.